# Aut(G) is abelian

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I've heard of this (open?) problem:

Classify groups G such that Aut(G) is abelian.

What I discovered:

- Any characteristic  abelian subgroup is cyclic.
- Center is cyclic.
- Commutators are cyclic.

What do true mathematicians know?

Comment: I assume by Zentrum you mean the center?

Comment: related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/9944/when-is-autg-abelian